# Saving workflow of XGBoost model for later use

Tags: r, tidyverse, xgboost

I am relatively new to R and therefore sorry in advance if this question is weirdly phrased or unclear.

I build an xgboost model based on the tidymodels framework as demonstrated by Julia in her youtube video about the topic (Tuning XGBoost using tidymodels - YouTube).

The problem I now run into is that I would like to save the model for later use (so I can load it into without building the model again), although I read online that saving it with the `saveRDS` function might cause compatibility issues in case of package version updates in the future.
A more robust option then seems to be `"xgb.save"` or `"xgb.save.raw"`, although to utilize this function the model should be of class `xgb.booster`, while my model is of class workflow.

This leads to a few questions that occur to me:

1. Does the compatibility issue also arise if the object is of type
   workflow, or only for objects of type xgb.booster?
2. Is there a way to convert a workflow to xgb.booster model within the framework of tidymodels that I'm using or should I adress this problem from
   another angle and try to find a better way to save workflows
   instead?

I would appreciate a response of any kind.

Below is some of my code to clarify (over_under is my DV and represents over 500 emails/under 500 emails):

```
xgb_bundes <- boost_tree(
  trees = tune(),
  tree_depth = tune(), 
  sample_size = tune(), 
  mtry = tune(),
  learn_rate = 0.06
) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  set_mode("classification")
xgb_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  trees(),
  tree_depth(),
  sample_size = sample_prop(),
  finalize(mtry(), data_train),
  size = 30
)

xgb_wf_bundes <- workflow() %>%
  add_formula(over_under ~ .) %>% 
  add_model(xgb_bundes)

set.seed(210)
data_fold_cv<- vfold_cv(data_train, v = 10, strata = over_under)

library(doParallel)
cores<-detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1)
#Register cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)

set.seed(285)
xgb_bundes_result <- tune_grid(
  xgb_wf_bundes,          
  resamples = data_fold_cv, 
  grid = xgb_grid,          
  control = control_grid(save_pred = T)
)

metrics_results <- xgb_bundes_result %>% collect_metrics()
best <- metrics_results %>% filter(.metric == "accuracy")
final_xgb_bundes <- finalize_workflow(xgb_wf_bundes, best)

model_bundes <- final_xgb_bundes %>% fit(data_train)
class(model_bundes)
[1] "workflow"

xgb.save(model_bundes, "model bundes")

---Which gives the following error:
Error in xgb.save(model_bundes, "model bundes") : model must be xgb.Booster.
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up after a good while:

1. The xgboost fit object lives inside of your model `workflow`, and the workflow thus requires the same considerations for robustness as the xgboost fit itself.
2. No conversion to `xgb.booster` necessary—you will indeed want to approach this by figuring out how to save the whole workflow.

As you point out:

- The xgboost fit element in a workflow ought to be saved with xgboost's native serialization functions.
- The workflow object itself contains needed information to safely/easily interface with the xgboost object, and can't be saved with xgboost's serialization functions.

The folks from the tidymodels team put together a new package, [bundle](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle), to provide a consistent interface for native serialization of model objects. bundle knows to call the correct saving/reloading functions for xgboost, parsnip, and workflows in succession. The `bundle()` verb prepares a model object for serialization, and then you can safely `saveRDS()` + `readRDS()` and pass between R sessions as you wish, and then `unbundle()` in the new session. So, for your workflow fitted with xgboost `model_bundes`:

```
mod_bundle <- bundle(model_bundes)
saveRDS(mod_bundle, file = "path/to/file.rds")

# in a new R session:
mod_bundle <- readRDS("path/to/file.rds")
mod_new <- unbundle(mod_bundle)
```

...should do the trick. :)